# c# Read text file directory on different computers OS and languages

Tags: c#, directory, filepath

I have issue that on my computer this line of code works.
But on Mac and french, japanese languages Windows it would give error:

```
  The path is not of a legal form.
  ArgumentException
```

I am just searching for a .dll directory and and trying to find file Tools.txt
Is there any why to find this tools.txt on different cultures and OS?

```
    string assemblyLocation = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    string assemblyPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyLocation);
    assemblyPath += @"\Tools.txt";

    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(assemblyPath);
```

Comment: Don't concatenate strings to build a path - use `Path.Combine` instead

Comment: I added this line according to your suggestion, but does mac has symbol "\" ?

assemblyPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(assemblyPath, @"\Tools.txt");

Comment: I don't know what a Mac uses as a path separator, but as far as I know the backslash is Windows only. Just leave it out as `Path.Combine` should add the correct separator anyway.

Comment: Side note: embedding file as resource is generally much easier to get right across platforms (obviously users will not be able to modify such file, but that should be desired behavior for files that are part of an application rather than some configuration)

Comment: In this case it a document for CNC tools, that are changed on weekly basis cnc is used. So manually tools are written to txt file in order to update program tool paths and avoid mistakes during fabrication. That is the reason I must keep reading the tool path.